# How to manually configure elasticsearch healthcheck

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-rest-client

Currently elasticsearch is autoconfigured by mentioning this property in application.yml file

```
spring:
elasticsearch:
    rest:
        uris:
```

But my requirement is to not keep this property in this file while still have health check enabled. How to manually configure that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was manually creating RestHighLevelClient in configuration class so in same class I just added below method to create low level Rest Client which is internally used for autoconfiguring health check and this solved my issue.

```
//    This low level rest client is used for health check 
@Bean
public RestClient Healthclient() {
    return getClient().getLowLevelClient();
}
public RestHighLevelClient getClient() {
    return client;
}
```

For more info checkout this - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/17464

Answer (score 0):

You can simply manually call the REST endpoint of [Elasticsearch cluster health API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-health.html), as you are only calling this REST endpoint, you will have all the control, like duration in which you want to call, what all to parse and how to notify/Act on the status.